# When are "where" conditions executed in an optional-unwrapping if statement?

Tags: swift

Swift 1.2 added the ability to unwrap multiple optionals in a single `if` statement, and the ability to test for conditions at the same time:

```
if let a = optionalA, b = optionalB where a.foo == b.bar && a.frob == b.nicate {
    // unwrapping successful
}
```

This introduces a dual hierarchy of conditions: evaluation moves forward only if optionals successfully unwrap, and only if each condition is met. My question, then, is how do they interleave? When are the conditions evaluated in this `if` statement?

I'm asking because I'd like to do something like this:

```
if let b = foo(i - 1) where i > 0 {
    // code
}
```

In this example, there would be harmful side effects if `foo` was called with a negative value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks at the moment, the `where` clause will be called **after** all `if let` checks were done without a `nil`. To take a closer look into how it works, I suggest Nate Cooks blog. He mentioned this on [this blogpost](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/).

> Using the new syntax, each binding is evaluated in turn, stopping if
>   any of the attempted bindings is nil. **Only after all the optional
>   bindings are succesful is the where clause checked**.

So it looks like you have to make the `i > 0` check as you did it before by doing it before the unwrapping.